# How do you resize the debug area height in Xcode 12.2?

Tags: xcode12

How do I resize the height of the debug area in Xcode 12.2?

In Xcode 12.2, the debug area takes the entire height of my window, (from the bottom of the upper toolbar to the bottom of my screen). There is no handle to adjust the debug area height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was typing my question I fixed the issue. It seems like this may be a bug. Press the green button to take Xcode fullscreen and then once again to go back to windowed mode. At that point the handlebars for resizing will appear.